# About executable jar in eclipse

Tags: executable-jar

I was learning about making executable jars for windows in eclipse and tried to make couple of them. Purpose of the simple classes I wrote was just to make executable jar. Jars worked fine if those classes were some GUI stuff (main method executed). But, I also made even simpler class that just prints out some message, created executable jar, put it on desktop, double clicked it, but, no message was printed... What happened? why simple, message printing class didn't execute when I double clicked icon for executable jar? How can I make executable jar which will also run the message-printing part of code?

Answer (score 0):

> *But, I also made even simpler class that just prints out some message,*

if you printed those using the `System.out.println()` method, then you need to run the jar from a terminal like **CMD** or similar... there you will see it...

If you instead just double click the executable **jar**, the `System.out.println()` methods are executed but you will never see them..

Comment: Thanks! So, messages won't be visible if printed with System.out.println()...  In what case will be messages visible? Only in GUI applications?